# Trouble with special characters

Tags: c++, special-characters

First of all, I'm a newbie in programming so you might have to be patient with me. The thing is, I'm writing a program that basically gets input and uses it to output some information plus the inputs in a `.doc`.

My problem is that I have some constant strings that output in a screwed up way when I use special characters like `é í ó ã õ º ª`.

I was able to fix it by adding `setlocale(LC_ALL, ("portuguese"))` but then I screwed my outputs of inputs (aka variable strings) that doesn't print special characters any more. Any clues how i can solve this? I've already tried wstrings and looked everywhere but couldn't find a single solution.

I can show my code here if it helps.

Here is an example of my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string a;
wcout << "Enter special characters like éíó: ";
getline (cin, a);
cout << a;

}
```

I can't make the constant string and the variable string output correctly in the console at the same time.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Definitely show an MCVE.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's much easier to get help if you show some code.

Comment: @guvante I'm using GCC, and i have no clue how to use another. hahah

Comment: @ThalesD.Silva: Nothing wrong with GCC, just that typically when it comes to non-ASCII character sets it is best to include what format your file is in and what compiler you are using.

Comment: An exemple:

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string a;
wcout << "Enter special characters like éíó: ";
getline (cin, a);
cout << a;
}

I can't make the constant string an the variable string print special character correctly at the same time in the console (and at the file)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using Windows. The Windows' Command Prompt default encoding is CP850, this encoding is rarely used anywhere else and it will display most special symbols differently from what you usually see in your favorite text editor. You can try to use the Windows APIs `SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);` and `SetConsoleCP(1252);` to change to CP1252, an encoding that is somewhat more compatible and should display those symbols the same way you see in the editor. You will need the `#include <windows.h>`, if its available.